# Compute the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{\frac{-a^2}{4t}}$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I'm struggling to find this transform. I tried to complete squares but the expression I had left was too messy. Could you please provide any suggestions/general hints/solution?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{ \frac{-a^2}{4t}}$

Comment: I'm sorry @mathcounterexamples.net I misread.

Comment: Which is the variable a or t?  Usually it would be a and the transform is standard.

Comment: t, a is a constant

Comment: https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=98045  It is in this paper.

Comment: Both Maple and Mathematics say $\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-{| a|} \mathrm{\sqrt{p}}}}{\sqrt{p}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} \exp{\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t} - st\right)}$$
Let $u=\sqrt{t}$, then you obtain
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\left(-\frac{a^2}{4u^2} - su^2\right)}\,du.$$
Do some factoring to get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp-|a|\sqrt{s}\int_{-\infty}^\infty du\, \exp{ -s\left(u-\frac{|a|}{2u\sqrt{s}}\right)^2}.$$
By Glasser, the last integral is just equivalent to a gaussian integral and so your initial integral evaluates to
$$\frac{\exp-|a|\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{s}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to Wikipedia, you apply Glasser's theorem when you have a substitution of the form $u= x-\frac{1}{x}$. Here you have constants multiplying the second term. What am I missing?

Comment: If you look at the more general form of Glasser's MT, you'll see that it's ok for there to be positive constants multiplying the second term.

Comment: Maple and Mathematica produce $\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-{| a|} \mathrm{\sqrt{s}}}}{\sqrt{s}}$. Pay your attention to the minus sign.

Comment: @Zachary, thanks again, could you please provide me a reference to that general form of the theorem?

Comment: Sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem.